# Convert RAW image into jpg in java

Tags: java, c#, .net, image-processing, bufferedimage

I have capturing device which is returning RAW 640x480 BGR. The docs to support it have only .net/C# code samples.

Here is a sample code they have in the .net SDK

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,
                                                            bmp.Width,
                                                            bmp.Height),
                                              ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                                              bmp.PixelFormat);

Marshal.Copy(faceImage, 0, bmpData.Scan0, faceImage.Length);
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

Here is the closest I got in Java but colors are still off

```
int nindex = 0;
int npad = (raw.length / nHeight) - nWidth * 3;

BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(nWidth, nHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
DataBufferByte dataBufferByte = ((DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer());
byte[][] bankData = dataBufferByte.getBankData();
byte brgb[] = new byte[(nWidth + npad) * 3 * nHeight];

System.arraycopy(raw, 0, brgb, 0, raw.length);

for(int j = 0; j < nHeight - 1; j++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nWidth; i++)
    {
        int base = (j * nWidth + i) * 4;
        bankData[0][base] = (byte) 255;
        bankData[0][base + 1] = brgb[nindex + 1];
        bankData[0][base + 2] = brgb[nindex + 2];
        bankData[0][base + 3] = brgb[nindex];
        nindex += 3;
    }
    nindex += npad;
}

ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", bs);
```

The red and green colors seems to be inverted. Appreciate your feedback to get this fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following part of your code seems not quite right to me

```
bankData[0][base] = (byte) 255;
bankData[0][base + 1] = brgb[nindex + 1];
bankData[0][base + 2] = brgb[nindex + 2];
bankData[0][base + 3] = brgb[nindex];
```

You are defining your buffered image with `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR`. The Java docs say

> The byte data is interleaved in a single byte array in the order A, B, G, R from lower to higher byte addresses within each pixel.

According to you, the format of the raw image should be BGR, too, hence the bytes in your raw image should have the order B, G, R from lowest, to highest byte, right? As far as I can tell from your snippet, you are copying Red channel value to Green channel, Blue channel value to Red channel and Green channel value to Blue channel. Copying the bytes shoud be rather

```
bankData[0][base] = (byte) 255;
bankData[0][base + 1] = brgb[nindex]; // B
bankData[0][base + 2] = brgb[nindex + 1]; // G
bankData[0][base + 3] = brgb[nindex + 2]; // R
```